# Unable to see anything in ListFragment

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-listfragment

This is my ListFragment Code.Which Creates simpleCursorAdaptor and then use it to populate List View.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Anuranjit", LaunchActivity.selectedDate);
    SQLiteDatabase allDatabase2 = new TaskDatabaseManager(getActivity()).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor allDetail = allDatabase2.rawQuery("Select "+ TaskDatabaseManager.KEY_ROWID + ","+ TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_TIMES + ","+ TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_DESCRIPTION + " from "+ TaskDatabaseManager.DATABASE_TABLE + " where "+ TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_DATE + "= '"   + LaunchActivity.selectedDate + "'", null);
    String[] fromColumns = { TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_TIMES,
            TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_DESCRIPTION };
    int[] toView = { R.id.Time, R.id.TaskDescription };
    allDetail.moveToFirst();
    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.layout_for_cursor, allDetail, fromColumns, toView, 0));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
}
```

THis Is the ListFragment Class.Now my activity_main.xml is as follows

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Main_Layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainContentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/Date_List"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now The problem is that I am not getting any data in int ListFragment.Code for Commiting the ListFragment is inside onCreate() in main activity

```
            Fragment taskFragment = new TaskFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.MainContentLayout, taskFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and fragment_layout.xml is

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/MainContentLayout1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

 <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="No data"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And i have just started studying android.

Comment: Try to debug whether you are fetching anything from the DB. Before `setListAdapter`, try to log the output of `allDetail.getCount()`

Comment: Yes I am not getting anyhting from the Cursor any Idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

You cursor is empty. The reason could be that the Date comparison might be causing the problem. In try using YourDatabase.query() method for querying the data base .
See Here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html